# How to add a delay to my JTable?

Tags: java

I need a delay in my JTable every time a row is added.

```
public void añadirNuevo(Procesos procesosArray){
    for(int i=0;i<procesosArray.size();i++){
        Object nuevo[]= {procesosArray.obtener(i).getNombre(),procesosArray.obtener(i).getTam()};
        nuevoTbl.addRow(nuevo);
        //DELAY
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Thread.sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) method

```
public void añadirNuevo(Procesos procesosArray){
    for(int i=0;i<procesosArray.size();i++){
        Object nuevo[]= {procesosArray.obtener(i).getNombre(),procesosArray.obtener(i).getTam()};
        nuevoTbl.addRow(nuevo);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // 1 second.
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

> Setting up a timer involves creating a Timer object, registering one
>   or more action listeners on it, and starting the timer using the start
>   method. For example, the following code creates and starts a timer
>   that fires an action event once per second (as specified by the first
>   argument to the Timer constructor). The second argument to the Timer
>   constructor specifies a listener to receive the timer's action events.

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds   
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           //...Perform a task...
       }   
};   
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```